# Upgrade Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I'm upgrading Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.3 and I was getting error quote_address table already exists then I removed quote address table from my database. After that I ran command setup:upgrade then following error start to come.

Comment: wat is the solution

Comment: The table is redundant so you got this error. The solution is that you should re-upgrade your Magento but you remember to reverse all steps before your upgrading.

Comment: re-upgrade means?

Comment: this error come on first upgrade command after push my upgrade code

Comment: i have database split

Comment: it means you have to upgrade again

Comment: yes but what i do for upgarade again push code again i try again n again